# What is my fallacy in the hello world finite loop?

Tags: c++, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void);
 
int alpha = 0;
while (alpha < 10)
{
    printf("Hello, World\n");
    alpha++;
}
```

error: expected identifier or '('

while (alpha < 10)

^

i am trying to make a finite loop to print hello world 10 times but the error keeps coming up. I googled it but all answers were for do-while loop. What is my mistake ?

Comment: `int main(void);` is wrong. You need `int main() {}` where the rest of the code is enclosed by the `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

`int main(void);` is a function declaration, not a function definition.

To define function, you have to use `{}` to surround the code in the function like this:

```
#include <cs50.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int alpha = 0;
    while (alpha < 10)
    {
        printf("Hello, World\n");
        alpha++;
    }

}
```